# signing Access Token and ID Token using HMAC in keycloak

Tags: hmac, keycloak

We are trying to configure Keycloak(OIDC) to issue Access Token and ID Token signed using HMAC but not able to achieve the same. Also we are not able to retrieve / generate the HMAC key in Keycloak which would be shared with the clients for signature verification. It would be of great help if anybody can share his/her experience if it's done this before. 
We are able to do all the staff using RSA but we are not able to find out how to configure HMAC to sign the Access Token and ID Tokens.

Thanks,
Upananda